# How to fix runtime error carousel-effect slide

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm tring to make a carousel effect in java with viewpager2 but i got a runtime error when I run the app in my phone and basically what I'm trying to do is to build a coffee app and i want to add this effect and this is what I'm [expecting](https://www.google.com/search?q=carousel%20effect%20gif&rlz=1C1GCEA_enEG998EG998&oq=carousel&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggCEEUYOzIRCAAQRRg5GEMYsQMYgAQYigUyBggBEEUYOzIGCAIQRRg7Mg4IAxBFGCcYOxiABBiKBTIMCAQQABhDGIAEGIoFMgwIBRAAGEMYgAQYigUyEggGEC4YQxjHARjRAxiABBiKBTIMCAcQABhDGIAEGIoFMgwICBAAGEMYgAQYigUyDAgJEAAYQxiABBiKBdIBCTYzMDNqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#vhid=zf6M8igQ1Yy9kM&vssid=l) so here is my SlideAdapter.java `

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder> {
    List<SliderItem> sliderItems;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;

public SliderAdapter(List<SliderItem> sliderItems, ViewPager2 viewPager2) {
    this.sliderItems = sliderItems;
    this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SliderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setImage(sliderItems.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sliderItems.size();
}

static class SliderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;

    SliderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    }

    void setImage(SliderItem sliderItem) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sliderItem.getImage());
    }
}
```

}`and this is SlideItem.java`

```
public class SliderItem {
private final int image;

SliderItem(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

int getImage() {
    return image;
}`
```

and this is main activity `

```
    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    List<SliderItem> sliderItems = new ArrayList<>();
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.coffee));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.cappuccino));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.latte));
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItems, viewPager2));`
```

So can anyone help...